# Custom LineMapper could not be registered from xml configuration when using spring batch and spring boot 2.2.5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Version using:

- Spring boot 2.2.5
- Spring batch core 4.x

There is only one following bean in the spring-batch.xml file:

```
<bean id="lineMapper" primary="true" class="com.batch.ContextSavingLineMapper" scope="step">
        <property name="lineTokenizer">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                <!-- This is to accept lines with incorrect number of tokens -->
                <property name="strict" value="false"/>
                <!-- Expected CSV column names -->
                <property name="names" value="#{jobParameters['columnNames']}" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="fieldSetMapper">
            <bean class="com.batch.DetectorRegistrationFieldSetMapper" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Class ContextSavingLineMapper is extended as below:

```
public class ContextSavingLineMapper<T> extends DefaultLineMapper<T> implements StepExecutionListener {
```

Message error:

```
Description:

The bean 'lineMapper', defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [spring-batch.xml], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [spring-batch.xml] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Note: I don't want to use `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue and I will take a look.

Comment: The project that I am doing very big, but I can give you a similar, this is project from github that I think they got the same problem: https://github.com/qwazer/spring-batch-step-scope-bean-overriding

Comment: Just imagine that you have only 1 bean definition as above and when you run the app with spring boot, you got the error message that you are having 2 beans with the same name(as I understand). it is so strange. I am using spring-batch-core 4.x, spring boot 2.2.5 and spring batch is configured by XML instead of using BatchAutoConfiguration from spring boot.

Comment: `lineMapper` is there any possability you can rename that ID? The error occurs when two beans are named the same not that > 1 exsists in the context

Comment: yeah, I tried to rename lineMapper to lineMapper1 for testing. And I've received the message : 
`The bean 'lineMapper1', defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [spring-batch.xml], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [spring-batch.xml] and overriding is disabled.
` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hitting this open issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1050.

> I don't want to use spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

Unfortunately this is the only workaround until the aforementioned issue is resolved.

Comment: oh, got it. is it possible to get rid of the problem if I move all XML configuration to Springboot Java configuration?

Comment: Actually, there are a few reasons from the community that we don't use spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true in the project such as https://brudenko.com/spring-bean-override. In case the project is big, and we have a team of 5 to 10 members. we would hard to manage the bean definition.

Comment: Of course, moving XML config to Java config with Spring Boot and `@EnableBatchProcessing` is another way to do it. I did not suggest that because I don't know what are your constraints. But if this is an option for you, then I would recommend it.